# How do astronauts and cosmonauts sleep on a Soyuz?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, sleep

Recently I learned that the Soyuz crew ship can take up to three days to reach ISS. I know that most of the time the travel takes only about 6 hours, but still:

In case something happens, you have to spend about 3 days in relatively small ship. It looks to me really small to do anything else than sit in your chair.

So, if you have to choose 3 day travel to ISS, how and where would you sleep?

Comment: I read somewhere that the 6 hour trip actually is less popular among the astronauts (but they accept any conditions, they are going to space) because then they are strapped down all the time. The longer trip alternative allows for them to float to the loo and just float overall. The first couple of days of adaptation to microgravity is called space sickness and involves flatulence and vomiting. One might make a bad first impression on the colleges with whom to live intimately the next 6 months. But they are going to space so they take anything. (And I don't think it is too bad)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two modules in the Soyuz that are habitable.  The Soyuz stack is three modules in total.

[image]
The crew launches in the middle module, which is also where they land and has the heat shield on its bottom.  The bottom module is the propulsion modules.

The top module is the Utility module and has the washroom facilities and the airlock. They sleep in the Utility module, while the non sleepers stay in the descent module.

In fact, the 6 hour ISS rendezvous is very new and only been used in the last few years, the normal transit time is 3 days.